# Mac OSX no valid sudoers sources found

Tags: macos, sudo, sudoers

I am always getting this error. What is the solution ?

[image]

Comment: Is there a user with an administrator account on this computer?

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says: your /etc/sudoers file has the wrong permissions.

the normal permissions (on OS X 10.10) are:

`$ ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r-----  1 root  wheel  1293 Sep 19  2012 /etc/sudoers`

so get a root shell in some other manner and issue `chmod 660 /etc/sudoers`
and/or the appropriate chgrp and chown commands.

To get a root shell, it all depends on what you have left as assets.
The failsafe method would be from a recovery partition, but booting in single user mode should be enough in most cases.

Single user mode: boot holding "Command-S" 
ref: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573

Comment: Through OS X v10.10 you could also use the [Repair Permissions feature in Disk Utility](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201560). If you're using 10.11, that feature has been removed, since System Integrity Protection makes it mostly (but not quite entirely) obsolete.

Comment: Good one Gordon! I didn't test if it works, but it's a good idea to try before you need to boot into single user mode or even worse.

Comment: Random, to start a Parallels machine in single user mode: https://forum.parallels.com/threads/boot-single-user-mode.327662/

Comment: I wasn't able to get my admin user to use sudo this way (i.e., permissions change didn't help). I was, however, able to issue the sudo command I needed (`xcode-select`) using single user mode. While I'm sorted for now, I do wonder how to redo the sudoers file entirely.

Comment: Dan, this is a pretty old thread. Are you having the issue with exactly the same error ? If you are,  also check the permissions, owners etc. on the /etc directory itself.